# Java LinkedLists and Queues- Validate my add method

Tags: java

So my add method should take the tag and add it to the end of the queue. My notes say that I have to do this to my queue first-

```
Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
```

Because Queue is the implementation and Linkedlist is the implementation. Did I do that correctly? And is my add method correct as well?

```
public class HtmlValidator {
    private html tag;
    private Node next;
    private Node start;

    public HtmlValidator() {
        Queue<Integer> q = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    }

    public void addTag(Html tag) {
        Node newNode = new Node(tag);
        if (tag == null) {
            throws new IllegialArgumentException;
        }

        if (start == null) start = newNode; //if queue is empty

        else {
            Node x = start;//traveerse the list until x points to the last node               
            while (x.next != null) {
                x = x.next;
            }
                //node is added to end of list
                x.next = newNode; 
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: What is the problem here, what are your code errors? Is what correct?

Comment: This code won't even _compile_ because nowhere do you declare `Node start`.  Which is sad, because the logic looks mostly right.

Comment: I changed my class definition, is it correct now?

Answer (score 1):

The logic of add is correct for use in linked list implementation. However class definition is missing for  Node.

Comment: Am I missing the definition for Node start? Would I add "private Node start" in my class definition?